# Calibrating probabilities of neural network

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, probability, calibration

I would like to calibrate the probabilites of my CNN classification model. I have a custom cross-validation and in each cross-validation run I'm dowing the following:

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
my_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
my_cccv = CalibratedClassifierCV(my_model, cv='prefit')
my_cccv.fit(X_train, y_train)
my_cccv.predict_proba(X_test)
```

If I'm doing it in this way, is this the same as the following?

```
from sklearn.isotonic import IsotonicRegression
my_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
ir = IsotonicRegression()
ir.fit(my_model.predict_proba(X_train),y_true)
ir.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Is not the same if you don't set the `method=‘isotonic’` for `CalibratedClassifierCV`, check the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html)

Comment: @Mr.ForExample But if I set method = 'isotonic' then it would be the same?